# Input file with btn-outline on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, input, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap form where I have an input file but i want it to have the design of a btn-outline-info so I do :

```
 <div class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg">
     <input id="signedAgreementFile" type="file" class="form-control-file">
  </div>
```

So I have a button "Choose a file" with next to it the string : "no file choice" in blue and both of them are in a blue box :

[image]

And when i go hover it the button become blue and the text white :
[image]

Until here everything going well. But when I upload a file the name of the file replace the "no file choice" but stay always white :

[image]

[image]

I have no idea why and how to correct that. I don't even have acces to this text in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `text-info` class to your input and add the extra CSS to stop the background color changing on hover.

```css
.btn:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


 <div class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg">
     <input id="signedAgreementFile" type="file" class="form-control-file text-info">
  </div>
```

Comment: If I do that I cancel the hover It's better but not what I'm looking for. I really would like to keep the hover.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg">
  <input id="signedAgreementFile" type="file" class="form-control-file" onchange="this.style.color='#17a2be'">
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Google chrome

Comment: I see. Strange behavior IMO. I've updated my answer to show what I consider an icky solution, but at least it works.